# How do I safely iterate over an optional list in Python?

Tags: python

I have a function which compares a file path against two lists of folder paths. It returns true if the start of the path matches any folder from list A (`include`) but doesn't match an optional list B (`exclude`).

```
from typing import List, Optional

def match(file: str, include: List[str], exclude: Optional[List[str]]=None):
    return any(file.startswith(p) for p in include) and not any(
        file.startswith(p) for p in exclude
    )
```

The function works as expected if all parameter values are provided, but fails with a TypeError if no `exclude` folders are given.

```
# True
match(file="source/main.py", include=["source/", "output/"], exclude=["output/debug/"])

# False
match(file="output/debug/output.log", include=["source/", "output/"], exclude=["output/debug/"])

# Expected result - True
# Actual result - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
match(file="output/debug/output.log", include=["source/", "output/"])
```

There was a PEP proposal to [introduce null-aware operators](https://peps.python.org/pep-0505/) that may have helped, but it has not been implemented as of now.

How can I safely iterate over an Optional list in Python without running into null errors?

Comment: Simply check if the list is none using an if-condition in the start. I think you could also try removing the `Optional` parameter and check.

Comment: Check if it's a list _before_ iterating over it? Maybe defaulting to an empty list, given the functionality in question.

Comment: I was a big fan of using empty tuples for these kind of defaults, like `exclude=()`. But I guess the typing annotations don't jibe well with that.

Comment: You might be interested in [`more_itertools.always_iterable`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.always_iterable).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the "or []" technique to ensure "exclude" is only iterated when provided.

```
from typing import List, Optional

def match(file: str, include: List[str], exclude: Optional[List[str]]=None):
    return any(file.startswith(p) for p in include) and not any(
        file.startswith(p) for p in exclude or []
    )

>>> match('foo', ['f',])
True
>>> match('foo', ['f',], ['foo'])
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to care if `exclude` is really a list, just that it's *iterable*. In that case, you can change the default to an *immutable* empty tuple if you change the type to `Iterable[str]`.

```
from typing import Iterable


def match(file: str, include: Iterable[str], exclude:Iterable[str]=()):
    return (any(file.startswith(p) for p in include) 
            and all(not file.startswith(p) for p in exclude)
```

This also requires switching `not any(... for p in exclude)` to `all(not ... for p in exclude)` so that the test is vacuously true for the default value of `exclude`.

Comment: How is this different than making it `=[]`?

Comment: @TheMyth See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: As long as you trust your code to be checked with a tool like `mypy`, you could get away with `[]` because a function designed to work with *any* iterable type can't do anything to modify `exclude`, so `match` is "guaranteed" to keep an empty default list empty. (If you tried to do something like `exclude.append("foo")`, `mypy` would catch that error because not all `Iterable` types support `append`.) Using `()` is just an added layer of safety.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `or` condition to check if `exclude` is `None` before iterating through it.

```
from typing import List, Optional

def match(file: str, include: List[str], exclude: Optional[List[str]]=None):
    return any(file.startswith(p) for p in include) and (
        exclude is None or not any(file.startswith(p) for p in exclude)
    )

# True
match(file="output/debug/output.log", include=["source/", "output/"])
```